# Android : how to use single button for multiple task

Tags: java, android, button

I have 1 button in activity. i want to use this 1 button for multiple task.

So how can i do ?

- If i pressed 1st time this button then it's change 2 button
- if i pressed 2nd time then it's update my data

but it's only work 1st time 2nd time it's not work

**see my code what i tried**

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
        {
            if (extras.hasExtra("edit")) {
                if (extras.getStringExtra("edit").equals("home")) {

                    etCompanyName.setEnabled(false);
                    etWebsite.setEnabled(false);
                    etEmail.setEnabled(false);
                    etPhoneHome.setEnabled(false);
                    etPhonePrimary.setEnabled(false);
                    etAddressLine1.setEnabled(false);
                    etAddressLine2.setEnabled(false);
                    etCity.setEnabled(false);
                    spStates.setEnabled(false);
                    etZip.setEnabled(false);
                    spContries.setEnabled(false);
                    //1st time use hear 
              txtSave.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_edit));
                    txtClose.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_back));
                    txtSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                    txtSave.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_add));
                            txtClose.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.label_cancel));

                            etCompanyName.setEnabled(true);
                            etWebsite.setEnabled(true);
                            etEmail.setEnabled(true);
                            etPhoneHome.setEnabled(true);
                            etPhonePrimary.setEnabled(true);
                            etAddressLine1.setEnabled(true);
                            etAddressLine2.setEnabled(true);
                            etCity.setEnabled(true);
                            spStates.setEnabled(true);
                            etZip.setEnabled(true);
                            spContries.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                    if (extras != null) {
                        Company value = (Company) extras.getSerializableExtra("company");
                        etCompanyName.setText(value.getName());
                        etWebsite.setText(value.getWebsite());
                        etEmail.setText(value.getEmail());
                        etPhoneHome.setText(value.getPhoneHome());
                        etPhonePrimary.setText(value.getPhonePrimary());
                        etAddressLine1.setText(value.getAddressLine1());
                        etAddressLine2.setText(value.getAddressLine2());
                        etCity.setText(value.getCity());
                        etZip.setText(value.getZipcode());
                    }
                } else {
                    //2nd time use hear 
                    txtSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Company company = new Company();
                            company.setName(etCompanyName.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setWebsite(etWebsite.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setEmail(etEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setPhoneHome(etPhoneHome.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setPhonePrimary(etPhonePrimary.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setAddressLine1(etAddressLine1.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setAddressLine2(etAddressLine2.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setZipcode(etZip.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setCity(etCity.getText().toString().trim());
                            company.setState(spStates.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            company.setCountry(spContries.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            company.setDate(Util.getInstance(AddCompanyActivity.this).getCurrentDate());

                            long isUpdated = myDb.updateCompany(company);

                            if (isUpdated != -1) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Company Update Successfully: " + isUpdated, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

***You can see my above code i can used `txtSave` button for perform 2 task but it's only change two buttons and i'll change data and click on button then it's can't perform***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, first declare global variable on your activity class file like below :

```
int count = 0;
```

After that add your click listener like that:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (count == 0) { // the first click
                count++;
                // do your stuff

            }else { // the second click
                count = 0; // initialize the count to limit the button click just for the first and the second time only
                // do your stuff
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create multiple `OnClickListener` for Button , Create only 1 and use it

example:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(btn.getText().equals("1")){
                //perform action for 1
                btn.setText("2");
                //change button1 to button2
            }else if(btn.getText().equals("2")){
                //perform action for 2
                btn.setText("3");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use single `onclicklistener` with `switch case`

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                swtich(extras.getStringExtra().toLowerCase(){
                    case "1":
                        // do something
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        // do something else
                        break;
                }
            });
    }
```